# Angular Material Button Content Not Aligned

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-components

In this angular component I am trying to use a mat-button to display different categories the search will filter through however when I expand the options they do not appear under the mat-button instead they show up on the left side of the page.

[This is a link to the example I was trying to follow](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview)

Here is the HTML for the component

```
<div class="section categories" id="searchBtnContainer" >
   <input id="searchInput" onkeyup="filterSearch()" class="form-control form-control-dark w-50" 
type="text" placeholder="Search for a system" aria-label="Search">

   <button mat-button id="categorySelection" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
   <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
     <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
     <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
   </mat-menu>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the component

```
.section {
      width: 100%;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 5%;
    /*  display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;*/
    }

.categories {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 2em .5em 1em .5em;
}

#searchInput{
  margin-right: .5em !important;
}

#categorySelection{
  margin-left: .5em !important;
}


button.active{
  color: white;
  background-color: #03A9F4;
}


.selector{
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: .5em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding:0.35em 1.2em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1em;
  border-color: #03A9F4;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.selector:hover{
  color: white;
  background-color: #03A9F4;
}


body {
  font-family: Lato;

}

.fill-space {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what happens when the button is clicked. I am trying to get the Item1, Item2 to display directly under the Menu button

[image: Example of what occurs when the button is clicked]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must import the material theme css, like in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e6d3gz?file=styles.css)

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```